# Testing for statistically significant difference between two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, group-differences

I have data of 8 temperature points inside and 8 temperature points outside a city. What is the correct way to test whether there is a significant difference between the two groups of data?

```r
Inside      
2.622213186
4.252151239
2.234700412
4.030813475
4.032630189
0.227646957
3.73592274
2.672609685

Outside
0.018780348
0.297691408
1.860159406
0.231511111
0.709386729
0.311395076
NaN
0.09834741
```

Comment: Are they matched, e.g. Pairs inside / outside on same day?

Comment: You have an amazingly precise thermometer.

Comment: user20637 took your question in a typical NHST way: (S)He answered the question whether the difference was significantly different from $0$, not whether the true difference is significant in the usualy sense of the term. It depends totally on why you are interested in the difference: How large would a difference have to be four you to call it "significant"?

Comment: There are 8 points in each group, each corresponding to 8 compass point directions. Does this mean paired t test is most appropriate?

Comment: @Bernhard: I did say "If ... you really, really want a null hypothesis significance test" and referred to the inter ocular trauma test (which doesn't originate with me). I, too, dislike NHSTs. I like the term "substantial" to mean practically significant.

Comment: @KieranCraddock The data is paired so a paired test is not inappropriate. Whether it is most appropriate depends on other things. In my answer the one-sample T-test of the null hypothesis that the difference is zero is identical to a paired T-test. The NaN means you only have 7 pairs. Note that the non-parametric test - unpaired and using all the data - gives broadly similar p-value, difference estimate, and confidence interval.

Comment: @ user20637 Yes, you did excellently

Comment: @KieranCraddock Yes, the standard answers to that kind of problem are the paired t-test (possibly with Welch correction) and Wilcoxon's signed rank test. There is no difference between  a t-test for paired data or a one-sample test on the differences of the data, so both answers given so far advise the same test.

Comment: @Bernhard I'm not familiar with a paired version of Welch's t-test. I'm not sure it make sense as you can't have unequal variances with only one set of differences.

Comment: @user20637 I apologize - I was distracted when I wrote that and should not have commented at all. Of couse, Welch correction is only for non-paired t-tests.

Comment: One of the groups has 6 or 7 measures of temp. what is correct number. You say 8 number in text. And what is indicated by NaN ? which test is proposed by yourself ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're not satisfied by the "inter ocular trauma test" (a difference that hits you between the eyes) and you really, really want a null hypothesis significance test then you'll have to handle the fact that, although the data isn't very far from Normal (within groups), the variance is far from homogenous.
[image]

The missing value for Outside (NaN) suggests that the data is paired, else you wouldn't have included it. We could look at 'Inside - Outside' but the missing value reduces us to 7 cases. The difference isn't very far from Normal[image]

so I'd be reasonably happy with a one-sample T-test of the null hypothesis that the difference is zero (this is identical to a paired T-test).

[image]

If you want to use all the data you'll have to ignore any pairing. To overcome the non-homogenous variance I'd use a non-parametric test, e.g. 
[image]

---

Edited to add:
@Bernhard  correctly commented that Wilcoxon's signed rank test is the common non-parametric alternative to the paired T-test. For completeness, here is that test with confidence interval. Because it's paired it only uses 7 pairs.
[image]

---

Edited to add:
@KieranCraddock commented "There are 8 points in each group, each corresponding to 8 compass point directions. Does this mean paired t test is most appropriate?"

On consideration, OH DEAR!!! This may invalidate any statistical significance test. Such tests assume that the observations are random, independent, samples from a population. If that were the case a single observation would consist of two values, one inside one outside. We have 8 observations (one has a missing value) and we might chart the data like this.
[image]

But you say the pairs aren't random, they correspond to compass point directions. Arbitrarily assigning compass points we might then chart the data like this.
[image]

A single observation now consists of 16 values, 8 inside and 8 outside, We only have one observation. We have no way of estimating the variation between repeated observations. We cannot apply any statistical significance test or calculate any confidence intervals.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is normally distributed, you have met the assumption of homogeneity of variance and your data points are independent, you can use a T-test or a paired T-test if samples are paired inside and outside city.

Comment: This data seems to meet the "inter ocular trauma test" ["hit between the eyes"]. Could anyone convince you that there is not a difference between those groups?

Comment: Lol agreed but he still may want a p value